# In JavaFX, why can't the MediaPlayer play files that has the characters '[' and ']' in its directory path? Other paths seem to be working though

Tags: string, javafx-2, media-player

```
private void setDirectory(String directory) {
    directory = "file:///" + directory.replace("\\", "/").replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    this.directory = directory;
}
```

That is how I am taking the directory inputs,along with the help of FileChooser class's method `showOpenMultipleDialog(null)`. This bit of code is working just fine. What I just don't understand is why are paths like "D:/Music/The Cure/Disintegration[1988-89]/One more time.mp3" not working when paths like "D:/Music/The Cure/Disintegration(1988-89)/One more time.mp3" are working.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [Media constructor](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) argument is a URI and [square brackets are reserved characters in a URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), so if you want an actual square bracket, you need to [URI encode the input string.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)